# How to set up in NetBeans 8.1 to successfully compile an OpenGL code which uses GLFW

Tags: opengl, netbeans, linker, glfw

I am trying to compile a sample code in the 9th edition of "OpenGL Programming Guide" using NetBeans v8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit x86. The sample code is triangles.cpp, the first sample code of the book, downloadable from [here](https://github.com/openglredbook/examples/blob/master/src/01-triangles/01-triangles.cpp). I have added information in the "Linker" tab of Project Properties dialog as follows:
[image]
You can see that "Additional Library Directories", "Libraries" and "Additional Options" fields are filled with needed and correct information (at least I think so).

However, when I build the project by clicking the "Clean and Build Project" button in the IDE, I got tons of errors:

```
g++    -c -g -I/home/me/ComputerGraphics/include -I/home/me/glfw-3.2.1/include -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/01-triangles.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/01-triangles.o 01-triangles.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/opengl1 build/Debug/GNU-Linux/01-triangles.o -L/home/me/glfw-3.2.1/bin/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/me/glfw-3.2.1/bin/lib -lglfw3 -pthread -ldl -lGLU -lGL -lrt -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi -lXinerama -lX11
build/Debug/GNU-Linux/01-triangles.o: In function `init()':
/home/me/ComputerGraphics/OpenGL1/01-triangles.cpp:27: undefined reference to `gl3wGenVertexArrays'
/home/me/ComputerGraphics/OpenGL1/01-triangles.cpp:28: undefined reference to `gl3wBindVertexArray'
/home/me/ComputerGraphics/OpenGL1/01-triangles.cpp:35: undefined reference to `gl3wCreateBuffers'
/home/me/ComputerGraphics/OpenGL1/01-triangles.cpp:36: undefined reference to `gl3wBindBuffer'
/home/me/ComputerGraphics/OpenGL1/01-triangles.cpp:37: undefined reference to `gl3wBufferStorage'
/home/me/ComputerGraphics/OpenGL1/01-triangles.cpp:46: undefined reference to `LoadShaders'
......
```

I had previously thought it is related to vulkan but now I have added -ldl and the errors persist. So, how can I successfully compile the triangles.cpp code on linux within NetBeans? Thank a lot.

Comment: "*It seems that `dlclose` is a vulkan function*" No, [it's not](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlclose.html).

Comment: OK, I added -ldl but the error message goes back to its origin: undefined reference to 'gl3wGenVertexArrays', undefined reference to 'gl3wBindVertexArray', undefined reference to 'gl3wCreateBuffers', ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I need one more library GL3W in addition to GLFW. Follow these steps (based on the settings I have set already in NetBeans):

(1) Go to https://github.com/shakesoda/gl3w to install GL3W, or use existing files shipped with the book.

(2) Set the linker flag to:

```
-pthread -ldl -lGLU -lGL -lrt -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi -lXinerama -lX11 -lXcursor
```

Note: the **-ldl** and **-lXcursor** flags are not mentioned in previous threads but indeed needed.

(3) Add gl3w.c and LoadShaders.cpp to the Source Files

(4) Add `#include <cstdio>` at the beginning of LoadShaders.cpp

(5) Compile and done!